# Regular expression for decimal number accepting 0 to 4 digits but no characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to devise a regular expression which will accept decimal number up to 4 digits.
I have successfully done it when a user **types** it in a text box.
Now, I'm trying to validate text box for **paste** operation.
For that, I have written a *jquery* function

```
 function pasteNumber() {
        var reNumber = /\d*\.\d{0,4}/;
        var theString = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');

        if (reNumber.test(theString) == false) {
            alert("You are trying to paste an invalid Number!")
            return;
        }
        event.srcElement.value = theString
        return;
    }
```

The regular expression which I have used is accepting a value like

```
44.aaaa
```

which it should not accept.
Then I tried changing regular expression to

```
/\d*\.\d{1,4}/
```

Then, it started to accept values like

```
44.1aaa
```

I need help to write a regular expression which will accept values like

```
4.1
421.11
467.111
438904.1111
0.1
```

But not

```
1234.a
489.a
435.aaa
412.1aaaa
1567.11a
```

In short, there should be no characters.

Any suggestions please?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only missing the anchors `^` and `$`

```
^\d*\.\d{0,4}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bC4gU7/1)

But, to avoid matching `.` and `123.`, you can enhance it as

```
^\d*\.\d{1,4}$
```

See [update](https://regex101.com/r/bC4gU7/3).

[As for anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), they

> do not match any character at all. Instead, they match a position
>   before, after, or between characters. They can be used to **anchor** the
>   regex match at a certain position. The caret `^` matches the position
>   before the first character in the string. Applying `^a` to `abc` matches
>   `a`. `^b` does not match `abc` at all, because the `b` cannot be matched right
>   after the start of the string, matched by `^`.
>
> Similarly, `$` matches right after the last character in the string. `c$` matches `c` in `abc`, while `a$` does not match at all.

Comment: Matches `.`, `.123` and `123.`.

Comment: Yesh, I know. `^\d*\.\d{1,4}$` should perform best. BTW, `.123` is a valid number.

Comment: No, that is an *expression*.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you! It's working. It was that simple! Just out of curiosity what difference does anchor make?

Comment: @ohal: [mathemetical expression](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102254/how-can-i-use-color-in-a-mathematical-expression-without-losing-horizontal-spaci)

Comment: Actually, when I think about it, we should likely be thinking about this in the context of `parseFloat()`, which would accept `.123`, so I guess it is in fact correct to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add some anchors and group `(?:)` the entire decimal part and make it optional with a `?`:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

`^` is for start of string, `$` is for end of string

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF9zX3/2)